# Xamarin Android: My [BroadcastReceiver] is not working

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to write a program in "Xamarin C# Android" to read Latitude and Longitude from GPS and display them in TextView.

The program runs without any errors, but there is nothing in TextView either. Because the Broadcast Receiver I made does not work at all. That is, when I put a breakpoint inside the OnReceive() function, it doesn't run at all.

In addition, I read everywhere that the compiler should add a line for it in the Android manifest file. But nothing is added in my AndroidManifest.xml Could it be a problem?

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using Android.Content;
using AndroidX.Core.App;
using System;
using Android;



namespace EhsanSensors
{

  

    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        TextView _locationText;
        TextView _addressText;
        TextView _remarksText;

        GPSServiceBinder _binder;
        GPSServiceConnection _gpsServiceConnection;
        Intent _gpsServiceIntent;
        private GPSServiceReciever _receiver;
        public static MainActivity Instance;



        [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
        [IntentFilter(actions: new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]

        public class GPSServiceReciever : BroadcastReceiver
        {
            public static readonly string LOCATION_UPDATED = "LOCATION_UPDATED";
            public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                if (intent.Action.Equals(LOCATION_UPDATED))
                {
                    MainActivity.Instance.UpdateUI(intent);
                }

            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            Instance = this;
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            _addressText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAddress);
            _locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLocation);
            _remarksText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtRemarks);

            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 1);
            RegisterBroadcastReceiver();
            RegisterService();

            
        }
        private void RegisterService()
        {
            _gpsServiceConnection = new GPSServiceConnection(_binder);
            _gpsServiceIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(GPSService));
            BindService(_gpsServiceIntent, _gpsServiceConnection, Bind.AutoCreate);
        }
        private void RegisterBroadcastReceiver()
        {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(GPSServiceReciever.LOCATION_UPDATED);
            filter.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
            _receiver = new GPSServiceReciever();
            RegisterReceiver(_receiver, filter);
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            RegisterBroadcastReceiver();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            UnRegisterBroadcastReceiver();
        }

       private void UnRegisterBroadcastReceiver()
        {
            UnregisterReceiver(_receiver);
        }
        public void UpdateUI(Intent intent)
        {
            _locationText.Text = intent.GetStringExtra("Location");
            _addressText.Text = intent.GetStringExtra("Address");
            _remarksText.Text = intent.GetStringExtra("Remarks");
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }




}
```

using these codes for Broadcast Receiver :

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
```

or

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
```

with

```
[IntentFilter(actions: new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
```

or without IntentFilter

Answer (score 1):

```
[IntentFilter(actions: new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
```

The Onreceive() method will be called when the phone is powered on, so you need to restart the phone.

And have you applied for location permission? If not, dynamic application is required.

For more information, you can check it [Broadcast Receivers in Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers).